# Search for Azure blobs in virtual folders using imperative binding in Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-functions

I'm storing blobs in virtual folders, using the current date as folder name.
I need the names of the blobs to be unique, but I also need to be able to search within the folders to pick certain files (e.g. filename startswith(id)).

Below is the code i'm using to store the blobs.

```
#r "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage"
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
public static async Task Run(string input, Binder binder, TraceWriter log)
{
   string path = 
   "container/{DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd/HH")}/{someid}-
   {someguid}.json";
   var attributes = new Attribute[]
   {    
     new BlobAttribute(path),
     new StorageAccountAttribute("<storage connection>")
    };    

    using (var writer = await binder.BindAsync<TextWriter>(attributes))
    {
      writer.Write(input);
    }
}
```

I know it is possible to search the folders using the SDK, but I really want to be able to do searches on virtual folders in a blob storage, using an imperative binding. E.g. i want to fetch all blobs stored the last 5 days.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, currently azure storage listblob method doesn't support search by time.

Firstly, the azure SDK also used the azure storage rest api [listblob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-blobs) method. It only support prefix as the filter.

So I suggest you could try to set the file with the date as the prefix.

```
e.g 2017-2-15-xxxxx.txt
```

Then you could use "2017-2" as the prefix to list all the blob start with "2017-2".

More details about how to use it by using azure storage SDK, you could refer to this [code sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-List-Azure-Storage-fe57b004).

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to use blob trigger to process new blobs you can use "Name patterns", something like `"path": "input/original-{name}"`.
   More details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob
2. You can store created time and blob path in azure storage table. So on step 1 you get all blob paths in time range and in step 2 you get all blobs. This approach needs additional code.